# How to create your own idp in .net MVC using SAML2 SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SSO and successfully able to implement using third party idps using SAML2.0. Our applications are in .net/IIS. My company wants to create its own idp because of cost associated with third party.Can someone please suggest .net create your own idp documentation,example etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some IDP that are free - have a look at [these](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60).

I would strongly advise against rolling your own - you'll find the cost and security issues of doing this are not cheap. Rather build on an existing library. There are some [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).